# Aws Internal ELB vs Hystrix Eureka

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, netflix-eureka

Which is be better architecture when developing application using microservice architechture for cloud (aws).

External ELB-> Application Api Gateways service-> Internal ELB -> low level services

Or

External ELB-> Application Api Gateway service -> Eureka -> low level services

what are the pro's and con's of both the approach.

Answer (score -1):

Spring cloud eureka is better in this case. Mix that with Spring cloud hystrix and Zulu works very well and become more feature rich than what available in internal ELB and you get more portability for your application (AWS, Azure, Bluemix...).

HTH

-Bipin